# Spark groupBy issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

Trying write simple program with spqrk. I have to group my data by one attribute of myStruct - LogData:

```
public class LogData {

    public String           m_Host;
    public String           m_Timestamp;
    public String           m_Request;
    public Integer          m_Reply;
    public String           m_ColumnByteReply;
}
```

What I tried:

```
JavaPairRDD <String, Iterable<LogData>> tmp = parsedData.groupBy(logData -> logData.m_Host);

JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<LogData>> groupMap = parsedData.groupBy(new Function<LogData, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(LogData logData) throws Exception {
                return logData.m_Host;
            }
        });
```

and simple:

```
JavaPairRDD <String, Iterable<LogData>> tmp = parsedData.groupBy(logData -> logData.m_Host);
```

And when I try to output resultData my program is failed.

Errors:

> 18/05/13 20:51:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1)
>       java.io.NotSerializableException: LogData
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>         at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
>         at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:195)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.spillToPartitionFiles(ExternalSorter.scala:370)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:211)
>         at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:65)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       18/05/13 20:51:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) had a not serializable result: LogData; not retrying
>       18/05/13 20:51:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
>       18/05/13 20:51:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
>       18/05/13 20:51:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: count at WordCount.java:92, took 0,088518 s
>       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) had a not serializable result: LogData
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
>         at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
>         at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
>         at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
>         at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
>         at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
>         at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Help :)
Thank's for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class LogData {
    public String           m_Host;
    public String           m_Timestamp;
    public String           m_Request;
    public Integer          m_Reply;
    public String           m_ColumnByteReply;
}
```

to

```
public class LogData implements Serializable  {
    public String           m_Host;
    public String           m_Timestamp;
    public String           m_Request;
    public Integer          m_Reply;
    public String           m_ColumnByteReply;
}
```